# Cannot Render Contentful content by using Angular Universal (SSR)

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, contentful

I am working on an angular app with Contentful CMS which needs to be SSR. I have followed all the steps mentioned here [Angular Universal](https://angular.io/guide/universal). But its just rendering the static content, not the dynamic content from Contentful. I have also tried TransferState API but its not working with Contentful. My code is

### app.server.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule, ServerTransferStateModule } from '@angular/platform-server';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ModuleMapLoaderModule } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    AppModule,
    ServerModule,
    ServerTransferStateModule,
    ModuleMapLoaderModule,
   ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppServerModule {}
```

### server.ts

```
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';

import * as express from 'express';
import {join} from 'path';

// Express server
const app = express();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 4000;
const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist/browser');

// * NOTE :: leave this as require() since this file is built Dynamically from webpack
const {AppServerModuleNgFactory, LAZY_MODULE_MAP, ngExpressEngine, provideModuleMap} =             
require('./dist/server/main');

const domino = require('domino');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const template = fs.readFileSync('./dist/browser/index.html').toString();
const win = domino.createWindow(template);
global['window'] = win;
global['document'] = win.document;

// Our Universal express-engine (found @                 
https://github.com/angular/universal/tree/master/modules/express-engine)
app.engine('html', ngExpressEngine({
  bootstrap: AppServerModuleNgFactory,
  providers: [
    provideModuleMap(LAZY_MODULE_MAP)
  ]
}));

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', DIST_FOLDER);

// Example Express Rest API endpoints
// app.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
// Serve static files from /browser
app.get('*.*', express.static(DIST_FOLDER, {
  maxAge: '1y'
}));

// All regular routes use the Universal engine
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.render('index', { req });
});

// Start up the Node server
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

### contentful.service.ts

```
private client = createClient({
    space: ENV.contentful.spaceId,
    accessToken: ENV.contentful.token
  });
```

Am I doing something wrong or need something different for Contentful?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by using Contentful API instead its SDK.
Use its API with HttpClient.

API Reference:
https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/references/content-delivery-api/

NOTE: Use full API url in HttpClient without any proxy.

Comment: What do you do about includes? In the SDK they seem to be merged, when calling the API directly they are a separate object

Comment: I had to write a custom method to resolve the Links by following this documentation: https://www.contentful.com/developers/docs/concepts/links/

Answer (score 1):

The Contentful SDK does not use Angular's `HttpClient` module to fetch data so the TransferState API won't work by default.

You first will need to use an adapter for axios as documented here: https://github.com/contentful/contentful.js/blob/master/ADVANCED.md#angular-universal

And then use `TransferHttpCacheModule` in your `app.module.ts`: https://github.com/angular/universal/blob/master/docs/transfer-http.md

Comment: I have tried this solution but now getting empty response from Contentful. It is sending all the requests to current domain e.g., http://localhost:4000/entries?sys.id=ID_HERE

Comment: This is a known issue with the `ngx-axios-adapter` library. Here's a workaround: https://github.com/patrickhousley/ngx-axios-adapter/issues/13#issuecomment-627326291

Comment: I don't know if you are still working on this project, but someone gave me an answer using the axios adapter: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61910699/contentful-js-using-axios-is-using-localhost

Comment: Just FYI, the `ngx-axios-adapter` is not really maintained. I've tried to used it with ng11 and this is a no go. 

The logic the adapter does is to intercept the axios call before it sends to the server, get  all request details and create a similar request using the ng httpClient. This is what I end up doing.