# contentful.js using Axios is using localhost

Tags: angular, angular-universal, contentful

This is a bit annoying! I am trying to use Contentful SDK for Angular Universal.
In the documents here:

https://github.com/contentful/contentful.js/blob/master/ADVANCED.md#angular-universal

and as per

https://github.com/patrickhousley/ngx-axios-adapter

I have installed `npm install @ngx-axios-adapter/core` then I adjusted my service to look like this:

```
constructor(private readonly axiosAdapter: AxiosAngularAdapterService) {
    this.cdaClient = createClient({
        space: environment.space,
        accessToken: environment.cdaAccessToken,
        // pass the adapter to contentful
        adapter: this.axiosAdapter.adapter,
    });
}
```

The issue is that it doesn't call the **cdn**: https://cdn.contentful.com instead it calls my localhost: http://localhost:4200 which is really frustrating.
I am not the only one that has had this issue, but I can't see anyone that has resolved the problem.

I found another question on stack overflow and they decided to invoke the API directly using **HttpClient** the problem I have with this, is that linked entries appear as a separate object, which is no good.

When I dived into the SDK I found some interesting options that I could set, namely `host` and `basePath`, but setting these did nothing.
Then I found a `proxy` config which expects type `AxiosProxyConfig` which also has a `host` paramter.
I set all of these:

```
constructor(private readonly axiosAdapter: AxiosAngularAdapterService) {
    this.cdaClient = createClient({
        space: environment.space,
        accessToken: environment.cdaAccessToken,
        host: 'https://cdn.contentful.com',
        basePath: 'something',
        proxy: {
            host: 'https://cdn.contentful.com',
        },
        // pass the adapter to contentful
        adapter: this.axiosAdapter.adapter,
    });
}
```

And it made no difference what so ever.
Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Does in work in dev mode without universal, e.g. just using `ng serve`? 4200 is not the port from universal, so I wonder where you are getting this from

Comment: On that note, 4200 is also not included in the SDK, finding out where this is coming from might be a lead. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with the `ngx-axios-adapter` library. Here's a workaround: https://github.com/patrickhousley/ngx-axios-adapter/issues/13#issuecomment-627326291

> ```js
> this.client = createClient({
>   space: appConfig.contentful.spaceId,
>   accessToken: appConfig.contentful.token,
>   adapter: (config) => {
>     config.url = config.baseURL + '/' + config.url; // fix for Angular 9
>     return this.axiosAdapter.adapter(config);
>   }
> });
> ```

Comment: I have done this and when I run `npm run build:ssr` and then `npm run serve:ssr` I get an error stating: Cannot read property 'keys' of undefined at AxiosAngularAdapterService.convertResponse